# Why can this underdetermined system in Ax=b be consistent?

Tags: linear-algebra

The question asks that, given a 5x7 matrix with rank of 4, is $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ consistent for all vectors $\vec{b}$ in $R^5$?

My attempt: If the system has rank = 4, this means that the rref has 4 leading 1's. With 5 rows, this means that the last row must be all zeros (because if there are non-zero entries in the 5th row, we could make it into a leading 1). The trouble is, my book says that the system may be inconsistent (which I agree with, given there would be an all-zero 5th row); however, *if* it is consistent, it will have 3 free parameters ($n-rank = 7-4 = 3$). I don't understand how these free parameters could exist -- if there are remaining digits in columns 5, 6, or 7 on row 5, wouldn't this make the rank of the system 5?

Comment: The rank is the dimension of the range. It being in this case less than the dimension of the codomain (5), the linear map represented by A is not onto. So there exists a vector b in R^5 which is not in the range of A. For this choice of b, the system Ax=b is therefore inconsistent. The number of free parameters (3), is the dimension of the null space of A, that is, the dimension of that subspace of R^7 which the linear operator represented by A maps to the zero vector in R^5. In a sense the null space and the range are separate, in that the former lives in the domain (R^7l

Comment: ...continued... and the latter lives in the codomain (R^5), but they are related by the Rank-Nullity Theorem: The sum of their dimensions is the dimension of the domain (7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Free parameters refer to the parameters that can take any value.

To make things easy, assume the matrix $A$ is diagonal; the last row is $0$ because the rank is 4. If the system is consistent, which means that the last value of the vector $b$ is also $0$, we get that the 5th, 6th and 7th component of the vector $x$ must satisfy

$$0\cdot x_5 + 0\cdot x_6 + 0\cdot x_7 = b_5 = 0$$

Which means that $x_5, x_6, x_7$ can take on any value.

In the general case if very similar: if the last row of the row echeleon form of the matrix $A$ is $0$, and the system is consistent, then it means that there are three parameters that can take any value and it wouldn't change anything.

Comment: So being consistent requires that the last entry of b is zero, if our last row is all zero? Also, I just realized that the last row could be all zeros except for the 7th entry, which would be a 1. This would make the rank of A still 4, but then allows for my 3 columns of free variables to be equal to a b != 0. Correct?

Comment: @AlexG Yes. In general the last row could also be filled with numbers, and the rank is 4 because it is a linear combination of the previous rows. So the last component  of b won't be zero but must be in the same linear combination with the respective components of b. Essentially if you reduce the matrix to row echeleon form you find that the last element of the "reduced vector"must be 0, and then do the linear combination in reverse to get to the value that the last element of $b$ must be.

Answer (score 1):

The general condition for a non-homogeneous linear system to be consistent is that the rank of the matrix of the homogeneous linear system and the rank of the augmented matrix be the same.

Suppose you have a linear system of $m$ equations in $n$ unknowns ($m\le n$), represented by a $m\times n$ matrix $A$, and let $b$ be he column-vector of the right-hand-sides of the equations.

If $A$ has the maximum rank $m$, then $\;\DeclareMathOperator{\rk}{rank}\rk(Ab)=m= \rk A$.

However if $\rk A<m$, there is no particular reason ensuring that $\;\rk (Ab)=\rk A$.

Comment: Interesting perspective with the augmented matrix. It doesn't change the number of rows, but it does add on an extra column. So if rank(A) is already full, then rank(Ab) = rank(A). But, if rank(A) is not full, then if `b` has some entry other than zero in the remaining row, rank(Ab) will be 1 more than rank(A). Further, this incongruity between ranks means that A has a zero row while b can have a corresponding non-zero entry, making it inconsistent. The only way it is consistent is in the special case that the `b` vector has a zero entry, in which case 0=0, but then A has a free parameter and

Comment: infinite possible solutions because of this.